# Character pointer array gets written over even when IF statement is false

Tags: c, pointers, typedef

I am breaking down a string by a designated delimiter and trying to modify a `typedef` structure depending on the first string. I realized that when i step through the code, the `typedef` structure is written over even when the if statement comes to false. I expected it to retain its old value from a previous for-loop iteration but it doesn't.
I was also thinking of creating local character variables that hold the values from str so that i update them accordingly and assign their values to `coord` typedef. But then it seems like am creating way too many variables.

My desire is to have the `typedef` updating the heading only when the string starts with a certain string. Otherwise, print what was available in headingPrev.

```c
typedef struct {
    char* utc;
    char* lat;
    char* lat_dir;
    char* lon;
    char* lon_dir;
    char* speed_kn;
    char* heading;
} CoordinatesHandleTypeDef;

const char *str_gprmc[7] = {
    "$GPRMC,125812.50,A,5741.1245547,N,01158.9460229,E,10.324,207.1,270319,0.0,E,A*0F",
    "$GPRMC,130019.00,A,5741.5393572,N,01158.6608248,E,14.013,331.8,270319,0.0,E,A*0F",
    "$GPRMC,130019.50,A,5741.5414303,N,01158.6591608,E,15.498,331.8,270319,0.0,E,A*07",
    "$GPHDT,3.0979,T*01",
    "$GPRMC,130132.00,A,5741.6055487,N,01158.3862843,E,9.536,174.0,270319,0.0,E,A*35",
    "$GPRMC,130132.50,A,5741.6042334,N,01158.3862498,E,10.783,172.1,270319,0.0,E,A*00",
    "$GPHDT,357.8596,T*06"
};

CoordinatesHandleTypeDef coord = {0};

    // Loop through for every string that comes in. Imitate USART End of Line....then process the string

    // We gonna keep the heading parameter out of the loop to get updated only once the data is available
    // This is because according to the datasheet, its updated onchanged. i.e when there is a detection in heading mismatches
    char* headingPrev = NULL;
    uint8_t* str[8] = { NULL };
    uint8_t temp[50] = { NULL };

    for (size_t k = 0; k < ARRAY_SIZE(str_gprmc); k++)
    {
        size_t maxStorableTokens = 0;

        // store the string in a local variable to avoid access violation exceptions for read/write operations
        strcpy(temp, str_gprmc[k]);

        for (uint8_t *ptr_token = strtok(temp, ","); ptr_token; ptr_token = strtok(NULL, ","))
        {
            if (maxStorableTokens >= 0x08) break;

            str[maxStorableTokens++] = ptr_token;
        }

        // if the string at index[0] is $GPRMC
        if (strcmp(str[0], "$GPRMC") == 0)
        {
            coord.utc       = str[1];
            coord.lat       = str[3];
            coord.lat_dir   = str[4];
            coord.lon       = str[5];
            coord.lon_dir   = str[6];
            coord.speed_kn  = str[7];

            coord.heading   = headingPrev;
        }
        else if(strcmp(str[0], "$GPHDT") == 0) 
            coord.heading = headingPrev = str[1]; 

        // Print out the updated contents of cood after every loop
        printf("UTC : %s, \tLONG : %s, \tLONG_DIR : %s, \tLAT : %s, \tLAT_DIR : %s, \tSPEED(Kn) : %s, \tHEADING : %s\n", 
            coord.utc, coord.lat, coord.lat_dir, coord.lon, coord.lon_dir, coord.speed_kn, headingPrev);
    }
```

[image: Printout of Results]

Comment: What is the `^ 0` for?  You know that does nothing right?  Just compare the result to 0 (or use `!` but without the `^ 0`).

Comment: its a bitwise operator for XOR...so strcmp() function returns 0 if strings match. i compare them with a 0 to see that they actually match....so XNOR is the other way round to check if things match

Comment: You're not making sense. `x ^ 0` is `x`; `... ^ 0` does nothing.

Comment: @HakimMarley `x ^ 0` will ALWAYS evaluate to `x`. It's about as useful as writing `x*1` or `x+0`.

Comment: Ya but my code is compiling well and gives the right results every at every step in debugging. Its the str variable that is being written over in some funny way.

Comment: You can't "build a typedef" at runtime. `typedef` is purely a compile time concept.

Comment: OK, i've edited the code to get rid of the bitwise operator in the IF-statement since i realized some people might not be familiar with it. I've rerun the code and still getting the same results as in the console i posted before.

Comment: If i can't build a typedef at runtime, which i think am not doing, can't i just update its member variables on the fly?

Comment: Note that `NULL` is for null *pointers*, not the null string terminator.

Comment: In the `else if`, you don't initialize all pointers in the structure. But you still use the ones you don't initialize. Perhaps you should have the `printf` inside the `if` and `else if` instead?

Comment: @HakimMarley A typedef is a concept in the "mind of the compiler", so to speak. It has no member variables. `typedef` simply creates another name for an existing type.

Comment: @melpomene i think you are absolutly right. But what i've observed is on the 4th iteration of the for-loop, where str[0] is "$GPHDT", the compiler shows that it has jumped to the else part of the IF statement, but as i step through towards the print, the member elements of the typedef has then been altered.....especially those in the IF-part. Thats where all the confusion is coming from...at least for me

Comment: Access violation writing location is what it says. Ther strcpy() likes to have the destination array to have a fixed index. Thats what i did with the array temp. Otherwise its what causes that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
char* headingPrev = NULL;
    uint8_t* str[8] = { NULL };
```

Here headingPrev and str are pointers they can only hold addresses not actual srings(or char array). 
So when you try

```
coord.heading = headingPrev = str[1];
```

this statement headingPrev only points to str[1]. This is equivalent to `#define headingPrev &str[1]` which is clearly not your intention. You need headingPrev to hold value of str[1] not its address. So, you what need to do is allocate memory for headingPrev. You can do `char HeadingPrev[20]` or use malloc/calloc for dynamic memory allocation if size of str[1] is not fixed.  Then you must copy str[1] to headingPrev using `strcpy()`.
So the final code would be

```
 if (strcmp(str[0], "$GPRMC") == 0)
        {
            coord.utc       = str[1];
            coord.lat       = str[3];
            coord.lat_dir   = str[4];
            coord.lon       = str[5];
            coord.lon_dir   = str[6];
            coord.speed_kn  = str[7];

            coord.heading   = headingPrev; //<---- This would still work since headingPrev would be same as &headingPrev[0] even after allocating memory
        }
        else if(strcmp(str[0], "$GPHDT") == 0) 
        {
           strcpy(headingPrev, str[1]);
            coord.heading = headingPrev; 
        }
```

You could also place `coord.heading = headingPrev;` outside `if-else` block since it appears in both if and else blocks.